# WSO2 upgrade 6.0 analysis, Is username replaced with user-id as input parameter for rest API's

Tags: wso2-identity-server

Till WSO2 version 5.11 we are using username as input parameter for many rest API's but in WSO2 version 6.0, we are using user-id as input parameter. Is there any documentation available for that, we are using user-id as input parameter?

Comment: Can you please mention the REST API name that you see the behavioral change of using username in 5.11 and user-id in 6.0.0?

Answer (score -1):

AFAIK the user unique Ids were introduced from IS 5.10.0 onwards ([what has changed](https://is.docs.wso2.com/en/5.10.0/setup/migrating-what-has-changed/#new-user-store-managers-with-built-in-unique-id-support)). Since then almost all the API implementations were based on the unique id. You can find the API documentation [here](https://is.docs.wso2.com/en/latest/apis/overview/).

If there is any backward incompatible API when migrating from 5.11 to 6.0.0 better to mention it in the original issue.